# My Blender duplicates the render

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm new in Blender. I have a problem. When I hit F12 to render my project with Cycles Render, the Blender duplicates the image. I think it will increases my render time.

[image: Duplicate]

So I just don't want this happen. Anyone can help? Thanks for the reply

Comment: Whoa! I have never seen that before!

Comment: In render window hit N button and deselect repeat

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise : Yeah, this is the first to me too, I'm so confused

Comment: @Denis : I did it, but now there's no image when I render it

Comment: @RoboticPuppies Hit F button to center the image?

Comment: @Denis : Oh, now the image's appear. Thanks :D

Comment: @Denis : Yeah, I forgot to hit the F button

Comment: @Denis Add that as an answer please :)

Comment: @Denis : Done :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To disable tiled render display, use <kbd>N</kbd> button in Render window to show properties panel, then in Display section disable **Repeat**. If the image is offscreen use <kbd>F</kbd> button to center it.

[image]